# Comparing Two Workbooks and Deleting Matched Rows

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, code-duplication

I am trying to compare two workbooks but unlikely upon Running the Macro, getting Error

> "Subscript Out of the Range".

Can anyone please help in Removing the Error? Thanks

```
Sub CompInTwoWorkbooks()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lnLastRow1 As Long, lnLastRow2 As Long
    Dim lnTopRow1 As Long, lnTopRow2 As Long
    Dim lnCols As Long, i As Long

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("listeappli.xlsx") 'Adjust as required
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Keyword.xlsx") 'Adjust as required

    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("listeappli") 'Adjust as required
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Keyword") 'Adjust as required

    lnTopRow1 = 2 'first row containing data in wb1 'Adjust as required
    lnTopRow2 = 2 'first row containing data in wb2 'Adjust as required

     'Find last cells containing data:
    lnLastRow1 = ws1.Range("M:M").Find("*", Range("M1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lnLastRow2 = ws2.Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Set rng = ws2.Range("A" & lnTopRow2 & ":A" & lnLastRow2)

    lnCols = ws1.Columns.Count
    ws1.Columns(lnCols).Clear 'Using the very right-hand column of the sheet

    For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
        For Each c In rng
            If ws1.Range("M" & i).Value = c.Value Then
                ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP" 'Add tag to right-hand column of sheet if match found
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next i

     'Delete rows where the right-hand column of the sheet is blank
    Set rng = ws1.Range(Cells(lnTopRow1, lnCols), Cells(lnLastRow1, lnCols))
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    ws1.Columns(lnCols).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please tell in which line you get the error?

Comment: VBA Editor is not mentioning Line Number. It is giving General Error

Comment: No, it shows the error message and then there is a line marked in yellow. Which line is that? Have a look at [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) for a tutorial how to debug VBA code.

Comment: When you get a run-time error the highlighted command in the VBE is the line giving the error.

Comment: It's in Line 01 and Line 09

Comment: This Line. Unable to Fix Error. @MarkFitzgerald "Set wb1 = Workbooks("listeappli.xlsx") 'Adjust as required"

Comment: Is the workbook `"listeappli.xlsx"` open in Excel already or not?

Comment: It is Opened there

Comment: Did you open that workbook **before** you start the macro? Or should the macro open that workbook automatically?

Comment: "Can't execute Code in Break Mode" Error coming on Line 09

Comment: @CLR Can you please Edit the Code.

Answer (score 1):

If your workbook is not open already and you want the macro to open it automatically you must use the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel).

use the following if `listeappli.xlsx` is in the same path as the actual file

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "listeappli.xlsx")
```

or specify the full path for `Filename:=` like

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\MyFolder\listeappli.xlsx")
```

Comment: Still same Error "Subscript out of Range"

Comment: but definitely not in that line.

Comment: It's in Line 01

Comment: it cannot be in line 01. Please read [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and learn how to debug a code properly. Also please always mention on which code you get the error. Line numbers are very inaccurate to talk about.

Comment: I know how to Debug

Comment: We need to know *exactly* which code throws that error. We can only help if you provide that information.